# Unable to configure Akka framework in Apache Felix

Tags: java, osgi, akka, apache-felix

I am trying to configure Akka framework in Apache Felix. I have used below steps :

1. I have included below bundle jar files in my project bundle

   - akka-actor_2.11-2.4.11_1.0.0.jar
   - akka-cluster-tools_2.11-2.4.11_1.0.0.jar
   - akka-stream_2.11-2.4.11_1.0.0.jar
   - config-1.3.0.jar
   - scala-library-2.11.8.jar
2. Below is the source code I am using in my Activator to create the ActorSystem:

   ```
   public class Activator extends DependencyActivatorBase {
       private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("COMMON");
       private static final String propertyPath = "config/";
       private ActorSystem actorSystem;

       public synchronized void init(BundleContext context,
           DependencyManager dependencyManager) throws Exception {
           InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(propertyPath+"sourcemodel.log4j.properties"));
           PropertyConfigurator.configure(is);
           logger.info("Bundle Activator Start");  

           actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("myname");

           Properties filterProps = new Properties();
           filterProps.put("pattern","/sourcemodel/.*");

           dependencyManager.add(createComponent()
               .setInterface(Filter.class.getName(), filterProps)
               .setImplementation(LoggingFilter.class));
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
3. At `actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("myname");` I am getting below Exception :

   > Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Iterable

//Edit

```
public class Activator extends DependencyActivatorBase {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("COMMON");
    private static final String propertyPath = "config/";
    private ActorSystem actorSystem;
    @Override
    public synchronized void init(BundleContext context,
        DependencyManager dependencyManager) throws Exception {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(propertyPath+"sourcemodel.log4j.properties"));
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(is);
        logger.info("Bundle Activator Start");  

        try {
            Config myConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(propertyPath + "reference.config"));
            Config regularConfig = ConfigFactory.load();
            Config combined = myConfig.withFallback(regularConfig);
            Config complete = ConfigFactory.load(combined);
            actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("myname",complete);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Properties filterProps = new Properties();
        filterProps.put("pattern","/sourcemodel/.*");

        dependencyManager.add(createComponent()
                .setInterface(Filter.class.getName(), filterProps)
                .setImplementation(LoggingFilter.class));
```

After editing the code I am getting below exception :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.event.DefaultLoggingFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:21)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:20)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.getClassFor(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:20)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:38)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:605)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:142)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:119)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.create(ActorSystem.scala:67)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem.create(ActorSystem.scala)
    at com.bitwise.tdm.sourcemodel.internal.Activator.init(Activator.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.dm.DependencyActivatorBase.start(DependencyActivatorBase.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:697)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2220)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2138)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:977)
    at aQute.launcher.Launcher.update(Launcher.java:457)
    at aQute.launcher.Launcher.activate(Launcher.java:354)
    at aQute.launcher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:238)
    at aQute.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:87)
```

Comment: Can you try to install the bundles you depend on as bundles instead of embedding them?

Comment: Yes, I have used the bundles jars of Akka framework on which I depend on. After running the application I am also able to see the bundles are in Active state on gogo shell.
   62|Active     |    1|akka-actor_2.11-2.4.11_1.0.0 (1.0.0)
   63|Active     |    1|akka-cluster-tools_2.11-2.4.11 (1.0.0)
   64|Active     |    1|akka-stream_2.11-2.4.11 (1.0.0)
   65|Active     |    1|com.typesafe.config (1.3.0)
   66|Active     |    1|org.scala-lang.scala-library

Comment: afaik Akka uses a lot of Reflection and Classloader Magic, so I fear parts of it will not play nicely with a OSGi environment and it's classloader isolations.

Answer (score 0):

Akka can be used within an OSGi environment. The limitation is that [a bundle must form one actor-system](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/additional/osgi.html#Intended_Use) (you cant have one actor in bundle A and send a message to a actor in Bundle B)

As Achim mentioned in the comment, Akka does a lot reflection (everything you provide in the application.conf file). So you must make sure that all classes specified in the configuration are imported by your bundle.

The Akka team provides a documentation about running Akka in OSGi (see link above).

The other question is which build-tool you are using. If you are using BndTools, you must integrate Scala in Eclipse AND Gradle.

EDIT: have a look at this working example https://github.com/lostiniceland/playground/tree/master/akka-osgi. Still, right now there is no Scala 2.12 support in Scala IDE so the example must be compiled and run from Gradle

Answer (score 0):

I have Akka running in Apache Felix OSGi here, also with Apache Camel together, you might find this a good example to start with.

https://github.com/PhilAndrew/JumpMicro